# how resolve PHP class defined in another folder

Tags: php

how does PHP find a class when the class is defined in a sibling folder of the running .php file?  The php file I am running is located in the `./examples` folder. The class file is found in `./src/Fedex`.

The use statement that `./examples/address-validation.php` uses to set the path to a class

```
use FedEx\AddressValidationService\Request;
use FedEx\AddressValidationService\ComplexType;
use FedEx\AddressValidationService\SimpleType;

$addressValidationRequest = new ComplexType\AddressValidationRequest();
```

when I run the .php file I get this not found error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FedEx\AddressValidationService\ComplexType\AddressValidationRequest' 
not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-fedex-api-wrapper\examples\address-validation.php
```

The location of the class is in the `./src/FedEx/AddressValidationService` folder.  Where both the `./src` and `./examples` folders are in the same parent folder.

Comment: You should make use of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to exactly counter this sort of issue.

Comment: Automatic resolution of classes and loading of files is done via a mechanism called autoload. You have to register things with autoload, and then you can just use them. Composer does a great job of helping you produce a registry, and offers various methodologies for mapping namespaces/classes to the file system.

Comment: @JAAulde is right. you have to register the classes with autoload at first. If you have problem with local addresses, use dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) to define correct location.

Comment: Do you used this API with Composer autoloader?

Comment: `use` statements only set a short alias so you don't need to type the full namespace every time; they don't have anything to do with class or file loading. To load code from other files you need to [include](https://php.net/include) them, or use a tool that includes them for you (such as Composer's auto-loader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a path to that class in the composer autoloader if you have one or if you have a custome loader you should teach that loader of to resolve class which are inside of the Namespace `FedEx\AddressValidationService\Request`

If you have define a `composer.json` file at the ROOT directory of your project you can define a [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autloader like this

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"FedEx\\": "./src/FedEx/"}
    }
}
```

after that you must execute `composer dump-autoload`

- Lear more about [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

If you want to create a custom autoloader and you don't want to use **Composer** which I highly recommand you can learn more about [spl-autoload-register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: In the original example file the autoloader (bootstrap.php) is included:
https://github.com/JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/blob/master/examples/address-validation.php

Comment: have you try to run `composer dump-autoload`